# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: `predictions` contains negative values

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've been trying to train a specific model in Tensorflow 2.10.1 varying the hyperparameters. For some of the runs of this code I get the following error:

```
# [...]
  File "train.py", line 95, in main
    model.fit(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/check_ops.py", line 407, in _binary_assert
    raise errors.InvalidArgumentError(
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: `predictions` contains negative values.  
Condition x >= 0 did not hold element-wise:
x (shape=(57408,) dtype=int64) = 
['-9223372036854775808', '-9223372036854775808', '-9223372036854775808', '...']
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting that error on `model.fit()` because my model has a sigmoid activation function, so the output should be in the `[0,1]` interval. This doesn't happen for every run, just for some of them, so it's been difficult to create a reproducible example. And usually it happens after many epochs, not on the first.

My model is defined as

```
def get_model():

  model = tf.keras.Sequential(name="my_model")
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(None, 137)))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation(tf.keras.activations.sigmoid))

return model
```

and my loss function is defined as

```
def weighted_binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred):
  """
  Implementation of weighted binary cross entropy loss.
  """
  weights=[1.0, 2.5]
  y_pred = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_pred)
  y_true = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_true)
  y_true = tf.cast(y_true, tf.float32)
  weights = tf.convert_to_tensor(weights, dtype=y_pred.dtype)

  epsilon = tf.constant(0.0000001, tf.float32)
  y_pred = tf.clip_by_value(y_pred, epsilon, 1.0 - epsilon)
    
  bce = weights[1]*y_true*tf.math.log(y_pred+epsilon) + weights[0]*(1-y_true)*tf.math.log(1-y_pred+epsilon)

  return -bce
```

To train my model, I'm using a code very similar to this (cleaned the code for better understanding).

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import History
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from dataset import get_datasets # builds my dataset object

tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)

class ClearMemory(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        gc.collect()
        tf.keras.backend.clear_session()

# get dataset
train, dev, test = get_datasets()

precision = tf.keras.metrics.Precision()
recall = tf.keras.metrics.Recall()
iou = tf.keras.metrics.IoU(num_classes=2, target_class_ids=[1])
model = get_model()
model.build()
model.compile(
  loss=weighted_binary_crossentropy,
  optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001),
  metrics=['accuracy', precision, recall, iou],
  run_eagerly=True
)

es = EarlyStopping(
    monitor='val_loss',
    mode='min',
    verbose=1,
    patience=10)
mc = ModelCheckpoint(
    'my_model.h5',
    monitor='val_loss',
    mode='min',
    verbose=1,
    save_best_only=True)
hs = History()
cl = ClearMemory()

with tf.device("/GPU:0"):
  model.fit(
      train,
      epochs=100,
      steps_per_epoch=750, # just the number of steps that makes sense for my dataset
      validation_data=dev,
      callbacks=[es, mc, hs, cl])
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The only things that solved this problem (so far) is removing the IoU from the callbacks list. Not adding it as an answer because I still don't understand the reason I got the error.